# Captcha for Laravel 5 install exception

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5.1 and tried to install this package:https://github.com/mewebstudio/captcha

After running composer require mews/captcha I get the following exception:

[RuntimeException]
Could not load package intervention/image in http://packagist.org:UnexpectedValueException] Could not parse version constraint 4.x.x: Invalid version string "4.x.x"

[UnexpectedValueException]
Could not parse version constraint 4.x.x: Invalid version string "4.x.x"

Any ideas why this happen? Thank you

Comment: I found the problem: I needed to run "composer self-update" before running  "composer require mews/captcha "